# find_in_batches does not use given order but uses id asc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I use ordering as it is?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank u!

see the code-

```
selected_catalog_products.find_in_batches(batch_size: 4) do |cps|
  # my code
end
```

Comment: How did you try to sort this scope ? What order do you want to set ?

Comment: I have the object "selected_catalog_products" which have the id randomly so I want as it is. The issue is "find_in_batches" is converting it into ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not possible to set the order. The order is automatically set to ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering work.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches

Comment: Using find_in_batches makes sense when scope is too big. In this case the batch_size should be at least 1000, but not 4.  I think you should do what you want this way: 
selected_catalog_products.in_groups_of(4).each do |cps| ... end

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark my answer as correct if you think so and vote it up )))