# An `ORDER BY` clause is added even though uninstructed

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to process records in my database like so:

```
rows = MyModel.joins("JOIN other_model ON other_model.my_model_id = my_model.id")
                      .joins("JOIN <some other join>")
                      .where("<conditions>")
rows.find_each(batch_size: 50, &:destroy)
```

I am not specifying any row order, so I expect that there won't be any `ORDER BY` clause in the final SQL. However, when I run this code, `ActiveRecord` adds an `ORDER BY` clause; the query actually looks like this:

```
... WHERE <conditions> ORDER BY "my_model"."id" ASC LIMIT 50;
```

This is a problem as I have many records in the table, and `ORDER BY` clause slows everything down.

I could probably rewrite my code so as to not use `ActiveRecord` to select the ids, but I'm wondering why `ActiveRecord` behaves like this. Why does it add an `ORDER By` when I'm not asking it to? Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Are you sure the slowdown on the database due to sorting is significant enough for you to worry about?

Comment: Please check your model, might be there is default scope for order by

Comment: @sawa this is not a duplicate of the marked answer and removing the order will have no impact. The issue is due to `find_each` as part of [`ActiveRecord::Batches`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) which clearly states *"NOTE: It's not possible to set the order. That is automatically set to ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering work. This also means that this method only works when the primary key is orderable (e.g. an integer or string)."*

Comment: @sawa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189937/activerecord-find-each-combined-with-limit-and-order might be a better choice for marking as duplicate. Other options include: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183745/each-or-find-each-or-need-smart-each/ , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725199/ruby-each-loop-in-order-on-sql-order-query-result/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005165/find-in-batches-does-not-use-given-order-but-uses-id-asc, etc.

Comment: OP: It is extremely unlikely the order by is slowing you down (ORDER BY on a primary key is very efficient). `destroy` however has callback functionality and will have implications as such (which is probably your issue). If you do not need the destroy callbacks then `rows.find_in_batches(batch_size: 50, &:delete_all)` will be much more efficient as `delete_all` is a pure SQL delete with limited code processing and no callback overhead.

Comment: @engineersmnky The question that I linked has an answer that says you can `unsccope` with nil argument to remove scoping that a re already activated.

Comment: @sawa you cannot remove the order by when using `find_each` no matter what. Ordering by the primary key is a requirement for batching to avoid race conditions ning

Comment: @engineersmnky Okay. I learned from you.